# how to make Y-label of subplots to appear only once?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a simple problem i need to solve, here is the example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3,  figsize=(6, 6))
for axs in ax.flat:
    axs.set(ylabel='AUC')
```

this is the output

[image]

I want Y-label(AUC) to appear only once(be shared) at the first subplot, and other values should remain. This is the desired output

[image]

How to solve this? Please I need your help

Comment: You set the label in a loop, so obviously every `ax` object is labeled. Move it outside the loop, and just label `ax.flat[0]`. See also: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html

Answer (score 2):

Since you're setting your labels in a loop, you're labeling all the axes in your subplots accordingly. What you need is to only label the first cell in your subplot row.

So this:

```
for axs in ax.flat:
    axs.set(ylabel='AUC')
```

changes to:

```
ax[0].set_ylabel("AUC")
```

I also recommend you to share the axis between your multiple subplots, since all the yticks are making your plot a little less readable than ideal. You can change it as below:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3,  figsize=(6, 6), sharex=True, sharey=True,)
```

The resulting image will be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `ax.label_outer()` provides a more general solution to the problem, especially when using grids with multiple rows. See:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html#stacking-subplots-in-two-directions

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3,  figsize=(6, 6))
for axs in ax.flat:
    axs.set(ylabel='AUC')
    axs.label_outer()
```